# Can I apply for a second Indian-Tourist Visa? Is there any time gap needed?

Tags: visas, india, tourist-visas

I am currently in India. I have a 6 months tourist visa, multiple entries, and my visa will expire soon. 
Can I apply for a new visa from India or Sri Lanka? Or I have to go back to my country (Romania) and apply there?
Is there a time gap between the expiry date of my visa and the moment I can apply for a new one?    (i.e. when my visa expires, I can go to ski lanka or my country and in 2 weeks to apply for a new tourist visa?)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I apply for a new visa from India or Sri Lanka?

You cannot apply for a new visa for a country inside this country (i.e. a visa for India from India). You can only extend the current visa, but if you get Indian e-visa, [you cannot extend it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77506/is-it-possible-to-apply-for-and-extend-an-indian-tourist-visa-whilst-in-mumbai).

Going to Nepal (or Sri Lanka?) and applying for a new visa there is possible, and that's what most people do.

Regarding the gap, there's no gap (for you) anymore. [According to Indian consulate](http://www.cgisf.org/page/display/261/26):

> With effect from November 30, 2012, the gap of two months required
>   between visits to India of a foreign national on a Tourist Visa would
>   be applicable only in the case of nationals of Afghanistan, China,
>   Iran, Pakistan, Iraq, Sudan, foreigners of Pakistan and Stateless
>   persons.