# What will happen if I overstay a tourist visa or can I extend it in New Delhi?

Tags: india, tourist-visas, visa-expiration, bangladeshi-citizens, new-delhi

I'm a Bangladeshi passport holder. My Indian multiple entry tourist visa will expire on 8 October 2018. I visited India on 20 August 2018. I will visit again with this same visa on 22 September 2018 for an interview at the Polish Embassy in New Delhi, as my appointment date is on 25 September 2018. They will keep my passport 14-21 days as normal visa procedure.

My Indian visa will expire on 8 October 2018 as the visa will be valid for only for 12 days after I leave my passport at the Embassy of Poland.

1. Can I stay 1-2 weeks after my visa expires?
2. Can I extend my Indian tourist visa in my own country (Bangladesh)?
3. Can I apply for a new tourist visa before my current Indian visa expires?
4. Are there any restrictions for Bangladeshi citizens entering twice within two months?

Comment: Regarding Q1, if the people at the Polish Embassy notices that you are overstaying your current visa in India, I would expect that it would affect the evaluation of your Polish visa.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77506/is-it-possible-to-apply-for-and-extend-an-indian-tourist-visa-whilst-in-mumbai

Comment: You will need an exit visa if you end up overstaying by paying a fee. Better to get an extension before by visiting the FRRO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to apply for and extend an Indian tourist visa whilst in Mumbai, India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77506/is-it-possible-to-apply-for-and-extend-an-indian-tourist-visa-whilst-in-mumbai)

Comment: @CannonFodder this is not an exact duplicate. The OP in that question has an e-visa. Here OP has a full multiple entry tourist visa. That question also does not deal with 2 month rule.

Comment: Online application to extend a visa seems possible however the form asks for your current state and city/district, indicating that you can only apply from within India https://indianfrro.gov.in/frro/menufrro.jsp?t4g=O66248B8 This page https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/india/entry-requirements indicates that a 2 month re entry rule applies to Bangladeshi citizens

Answer (score 6):

> Can I stay 1-2 weeks after my visa expires?

No, you can’t:

> Regardless of the duration of the valid visa, the maximum duration of stay in India is limited to 6 months (180 days) on each visit. Extension of stay is not granted on tourist visas and it can not be converted into any other visa.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiao7PXh6DkAhWC-qQKHVOgCGwQFjABegQIChAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.immihelp.com%2Fnri%2Findiavisa%2Ftourist-visa-india.html&usg=AOvVaw3dzRf1em5Iy2_Cfgxs3cjD))

If so, be prepared to pay the equivalent of US $30>

> An exit visa is required to leave India. The authorities will look into the reason as to why the overstay happened and then levy fine or penalty. The penalty is usually around US $30 or equivalent in Indian Currency for a short duration of overstay if the overstay is condoned by the authorities.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwiao7PXh6DkAhWC-qQKHVOgCGwQFjADegQICxAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnriinformation.com%2Fquestions18%2Fquestions1092.htm&usg=AOvVaw2jYIywdjsutFsoHmxZQfTh))

> Can I extend my Indian tourist visa in my own country (Bangladesh)?

No you won’t, as when you exit India you should wait 90 days before re-entering:

> Any holder of a tourist visa who wishes to visit another country during their stay in India must wait at least two months before re-entering. This time will be factored into the total duration of your visa (usually either 90 or 180 days).

([Source](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293860-i511-k6440963-Tourist_visa_extension-India.html))

> Can I apply for a new tourist visa before my current Indian visa expires?

You can apply 60 days before the end of your visa:

> The advice is to submit the application 60 days before the expiration date of the current visa. The applicant can renew their visa either at the registration office or on the website of the Bureau of the immigration department.

([Source](https://info.viselio.com/india-visa-extension-renewal/))

> Are there any restrictions for Bangladeshi citizens entering twice within two months?

See number 2.